# Exception when running in service but not debugging

Tags: c#, async-await, static

I have some code that follows the following steps.

1. Makes an Http call and logs the result
2. Converts the API response class to the local model
3. Returns the model

When running the code locally with debugging, the flow is fine. Once it is in the server, we receive the exception from step 2. Anyone able to please help understand why?

The code:

```
// this is in an async task function
            try
            {
                // send api request
                var status = await GetStatus(id);

                // convert to model class
                var statusModel = RequestModelMapper.GetStatusResponseToStatusModel(status);

                return statusModel;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Error getting status of {id} received exception {ex}", id, ex);
                throw;
            }
```

`RequestModelMapper` is a static class with static methods, this one particularly being like so:

```
 public static StatusModel GetStatusResponseToStatusModel(
            GetStatusResponse getStatusResponse)
        {
            return new StatusModel
            {
                Id = getStatusResponse.id,
                Status = InnerStatusToStatusModel(getStatusResponse.Status), // this function is also static, takes the string and returns an enum value via switch case
                MyList = getStatusResponse.EventRequests.Select(MyListResponseToMyListStatusModel).ToList()
            };
        }


 private static MyListStatusModel MyListResponseToMyListStatusModel(MyListResponse myListResponse)
        {
            return new MyListStatusModel 
            {
                Lists = myListResponse.Messages.Select(GetMessageStatusResponseToMyListStatusModel).ToList()
            };
        }
```

The exception is:

> received exception System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
> at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.Select[TSource,TResult](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 selector)
> at MyPath.RequestModelMapper.GetStatusResponseToStatusModel(GetStatusResponse getStatusResponse)
> at MyPath.MyClass.GetStatus(String id)

Is there some sort of hidden race condition here? If not, is there a different explanation for the exception in the server but not for local runs?

Comment: I guess the `GetStatus` method returns different results locally and on the server. One of your lists where you call `Select` is null

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the response data coming back from the server? Based on the error message it looks like one of your collections that your selecting is null.

So it could be:  myListResponse.Messages.Select(GetMessageStatusResponseToMyListStatusModel).ToList()

Or it could be

getStatusResponse.EventRequests.Select(MyListResponseToMyListStatusModel).ToList()